# How can call my Broadcast receiver only when any Application launched?

Tags: android

I want to block some applications from the user as per user accessibility . For that i can not restrict installation of application in android but i think we can block the application to run so that user can not use(even launch) any of restricted applications. so my question is how can do this ? Means how can start a receiver when any of the application launch in android device ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can start a service within the service you can create a list of all the apps which you want to lock

you can get the list of all the apps using this:

for (ResolveInfo resInfo : pkgAppsList) {
   ActivityInfo actInfo = resInfo.activityInfo;
   ApplicationInfo AppInfo = actInfo.applicationInfo;
   CharSequence AppName = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(AppInfo);

set your locked apps then whenever a app is launched fetch its details using this:

foregroundAppPackageInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
and check whether it is locked or not

Answer (score 1):

If this feature is possible, it would be pretty scary!
Some applications may sabotage your device, by not allowing certain applications. Too much for abuse, me thinks!
It might be possible in the earliest versions, but I think google must have figured out by now those loop holes.